# Simple Update Function MySQL

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a CMS coded in ColdFusion 9 with basic login functions to work with a socket server that I'm working with. Recently I setup a "VIP" subscription w/payment, but then I realized, I have no SQL to remove the subscription after 2 months have passed. Here's my basic request; I need some SQL to execute automatically if the timestamp value of `date_purchased` is 2 months old. It needs to delete the row in `vip_purchases` for the session user (Only the user), and update the column `vip` to `0` in `users`.

I need this to execute for the session username ONLY, and only if the timestamp is 2 weeks old, and ONLY if the value in VIP is `1`.
I was thinking along the lines of:

```
update users set vip = 0 where username = session.username if vip = 1 if date_purchased = 2 months old
```

I realize this isn't SQL, that was just to attempt to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. :)

```
UPDATE users
SET vip = 0
WHERE username = sessionname 
AND vip = 1 
AND date_purchased <= (today - number of days wanted)
```

You'll need to replace the last part of the `WHERE` (the `today -` part) with whatever timeframe condition you want; your post is confusing, as it mentions `2 weeks old` and `2 months old` in the same context.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized I used both units of measurement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to run this reoccurring task via Coldfusion (as opposed to internal to the MySQL database), you should setup a Scheduled Task via the Coldfusion Administrator. The task could launch a script once daily to clean up all of the old accounts.

Once that is decided, you can create a .cfm or .cfc file that includes the task.

This can be a simple file that includes a cfquery or a cfstoredproc depending on where you want your logic to run. Cfquery will run the logic on the web server in Coldfusion, the cfstoredproc will ask the database server to run MySQL logic on the database server. It would likely be best to run it as a stored procedure.

In this case, you would not need to even check the username. Just SELECT then loop over and UPDATE all users where vip = 1 and the date_purchased has expired.

Comment: I'm using the first answer, but I have an idea of where I can put your suggestion as well! Thanks, guys.